# How can I create custom shapes in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes, func

I'm learning swiftui and I want to create some shapes in my app.

I instead of repeating my code I decided to create a function to display the shape.

I tried to create a func that contains the shape and call it where I need it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
               rect()
            }
        }
    }
}

func rect() {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .cornerRadius(18)
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

What is my problem here, and how can I fix it so I can create different styles for buttons, textboxes, images, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506102/12299030?

Comment: No I want a way not only for shapes. I want to customize other things like textboxes and button styles instead of having to rewrite the code in the view.

Comment: The answer you accepted is not what you are looking in your question! You asked for a function for returning a Shape not a View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, instead of defining a function, define a new view:

```
struct MyRect: View {

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .cornerRadius(18)
    }
}

// Embed with 'MyRect()'
```

Alternatively, the `func rect` in your code could have a return type `some View`:

```
func rect() -> some View {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .cornerRadius(18)
}

// Embed with 'rect()'
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a function for showing the view one must create @ViewBuilder function and return some View.

You need to do something like this :-

```
      @ViewBuilder func rect() -> some View {
   
              Rectangle()
                  .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                  .cornerRadius(18)

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The func rect is of type `Void`, the body in your `View` returns `some View`. You should make your function's return type conform to `View`, so either:

1. return a Shape `func rect() -> Shape {`
2. return a View `func rect() -> some View {`

Do note that if go with option number 1 you cannot return anything that is not a `Shape`.